# Attempting to click a button in Python using Selenium WebDriver (Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, element, clicking

I am attempting to click a button on a html page using Python and selenium web driver.

This is the source code of the page http://pastebin.com/112g1Gje.

I believe the relevant portion is at the end. I'm trying to click the button that says "Message"

Normally I would do something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("message-modal").click()
```

However that doesn't work.

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("message_label").click()
driver.execute_script('document.getElementByName(" Message ").click();')
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("message-senderId").click();')
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("message-    label").addEventListener("submit", function())')
```

...etc.

All of them don't work.
For the stars by the way I had the same issue. It was hard to click it, but I figured this part out. This worked:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("star_41094_4").checked = true;')
```

I think this page is switching up the numbers for the star. So that number may not work right now. But that's a separate issue. Does anybody know?

EDIT: I have asked a moderator to delete this thread. I had a number of things wrong here. I am creating a new one.

Comment: message-modal is div id not button  in http://pastebin.com/112g1Gje.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? Do you an "element not found" error? Some other error? Does your program crash?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Open Message Modal']").click()
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: This doesn't work :/.. also message modal is the div. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to code a button that opens that message-modal. Better create that button first like.

```
<button class="btn" id="btn-message-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#message-modal"> Open Message Modal</btn>\
```

Then try this:

driver.find_element_by_id("btn-message-modal").click()

**PS**

message-modal is the id of the modal container that is why nothing happens
On this code

```
driver.find_element_by_id("message-modal").click()
```

Comment: Excuse me but how do I code a button that opens that? Also I realized that mistake. But how do I code a button that opens that..... I'm running this code on a webpage online?

Answer (score -1):

driver.find_element_by_classname("btn").click() works